# VPN endpoint for my IPhone?

Tags: vpn, iphone

For my company I need to setup a VPN endpoint so that my users can securely login to my network.

Can anyone recommend a good server side software product/solution that can allow my Iphones to communicate to our network using VPN? (No VPN hardware solution to start with due to budget limits).

Also, is it possible to force all communication sent over the wire to go through the VPN tunnel? I mean traffic to non-company-network servers? Like web-sites....

Answer (score 5):

the iPhone supports common VPN technologies like IPSec PPTP and L2TP

this [Iphone VPN Guide](http://images.apple.com/iphone/enterprise/docs/iPhone_VPN.pdf) might answer some of your questions about it

For a basic set up you might want to get a spare machine and loading [Smoothwall](http://smoothwall.org/) or [ipcop](http://www.ipcop.org/) linux distributions. They have IPSec support built in, so it's quite easy to set up. This way you'll be able to experiment with some inexpensive hardware; figure out what works for you and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try AccessMyLan, it's easy and cheap.  Plus it requires no up-front setup costs and can be deployed easily.  They support iPhones too.